# How to provide a list of objects as CLI parameter to Jib?

Tags: java, docker, maven, command-line-interface, jib

I have multiple Java Applications that depend on the directory `config/` at the root of each repository.
When building images of these apps with jib-maven-plugin, Jib does not copy this directory by default.

Specifying `extraDirectories` works when configuring via `pom.xml` as `<from>` and `<into>` can be set:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <extraDirectories>
            <paths>
              <path>
                <from>./config</from>
                <into>/config</into>
              </path>
            </paths>
          </extraDirectories>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Though I'd rather configure Jib via CLI parameters.

`-Djib.extraDirectories.paths=./config` works for copying all the contents of `config/` to the root of the container. Though I need the files to be copied to `/config/*`.

This brings me to the question whether it is possible to provide a list of objects to `-Djib.extraDirectories.paths`?
As in `-Djib.extraDirectories.paths={from=./config,into=/config},{from=/another/dir,into=/dir/in/image}` (whatever the right syntax would be?).